# Windows 10 Home - Trying to create mirrored hard drives but option does not appear in Disk Management

Tags: windows-10, mirroring

I am trying to follow the steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGwuffZAR1Y) to create a mirrored hard drive on my Windows PC running Windows 10 Home build 19045.2486. I have 2 4TB SSDs and I want one of these SSDs to constantly be updated with an exact mirror image of the other.

However, when I open my disk management to create a new mirrored volume, the option does not even appear at all. It's not greyed out; it just isn't there whatsoever. I am referring to the 0:46 mark in the YouTube video linked above.
[image of my options when right clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWTfO.png)

What is causing this and how can I get the option to create a new mirrored volume? The disk in question is 4TB in size, it's a basic disk (not dynamic), and is GPT formatted. It currently has no allocated space or volumes on it.

Comment: Dynamic Disks are a Professional only feature

Answer (score 0):

Windows no longer does RAID, like mirroring, using Disk Management.  You need to use [Storage Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/storage-spaces-in-windows-b6c8b540-b8d8-fb8a-e7ab-4a75ba11f9f2).  You can create a mirror using the methods described in the article.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that. I can't seem to find an article on how to do it with an existing drive. To make a new two-way mirror, it seems that you need 2 empty drives to set it up. I have one drive with a bunch of data on it and I want to be able to set up a secondary mirror drive retroactively without having to copy over the data on the first drive to somewhere else and reformatting it. Do you know of a way to do this?

Comment: @J.Doe cant be done.  Both drives need to be blank to start with.